# How to find the shortest Path in R

Tags: r

Problem:
I have a data frame with a set of points with Lat and Long information. We need to start from A and traverse through each of the other nodes once and end at any point. The objective is to minimise the total haversine distance travelled.

```
df <- data.frame("name" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
"lon" = c(-73.001, 23.231, 1.23, 115.40, -87.98), 
"lat" = c(40.21, 32.78, -34.30, 21.92, -12.2))
```

Generating all permutation will not work if the number of points is large. I have tried to use iGraph package but couldnt understand how to solve this problem. With distm (gepsphere), I can get all distance matrix but I dont know how to proceed.

Please help me in figuring out how to do this. I am looking for a Solution in R.

Comment: Isn't this the Travelling Salesman Problem on a sphere?

Answer (score 4):

As @42 already noted, this seems like a Travelling Salesman Problem. So you might try

```
library(TSP)
library(geosphere)
d <- distm(as.matrix(df[, -1]))
tour <- solve_TSP(TSP(d, labels=df$name), 
                  method="nearest_insertion", 
                  control=list(start=1L))
labels(tour)
# [1] "A" "D" "B" "C" "E"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried various methods but I cant  get the order CDBAE which seems to be the shortest path by total distance. This path is evident by plotting them on a map. How can we get that? Any ideas.

Comment: Is that so? I must admit that I cannot judge great circle distances by eye. Check `rownames(df) <- df$name; tour_length2 <- function(x) { require(sp); LinesLength(Lines(list(Line(df[x, c("lon", "lat")])), ID="1"), longlat=TRUE) }; tour_length2(c("E", "A", "B", "C", "D")); tour_length2(c("C", "D", "B", "A", "E"))` - the 1st one seems to be shorter than your "optimum". That is, if the measure is correct. Besides that, you said you wanted to start at A...?